# Living in Texas and remote working for job in NC. Should I pay state taxes for NC?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, texas, working-at-home

I am full time resident of Texas where there is no state tax but I am remote-working for company located in NC. Do I need to pay state tax for NC? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related answer: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/46642/30183

Comment: Are you an employee (receiving a w2) or are you a contracted laborer that will receive a 1099?