# Taxes for remote US worker who wants to travel between states

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax

Person A works for Company C.
Most employees of Company C are remote workers, including A.
Company C is in USA. Person A resides in Texas.

As A can work remotely from any state in US, A wants to lead the life of a tech nomad and travel between all 50 states.

In such a scenario, how will the taxes work?

Will A have to pay state income tax based on whichever state he is currently located in?

Will it be a pain for HR to deal with A's taxes?

Is there any easier way to deal with taxes? A is hell bent on travelling all the 50 states over the next 2-3 years.

Comment: What state is the company in?

Comment: Company C has main offices in Virginia

Answer (score 3):

That's going to depend on the non-resident tax laws of the state in which the company for which you are doing the work resides.

If you are an actual employee (you receive a W2) it seems like you're fairly likely to need to file a non-resident tax return. Regardless of whether or not you actually end up owing any taxes. [This article has a little more information on the subject if you want to explore it some more.](https://www.rapidtax.com/blog/work-remotely-pay-taxes/)

Of course, in Texas, you will owe no state income tax regardless.

Oh, and most decently sized companies will be able to handle this situation with ease from an HR standpoint. It's a fairly common scenario.

Comment: thank you. and yes, person works as a fulltime W-2 employee.

Comment: You generally have to maintain residence somewhere to keep you car registration and insurance active. There are companies who provide an address for this purpose for full-time RVers. Some friends did this and changed residence from California to Texas.

Comment: @mkennedy Interesting addition to the equation I hadn't addressed.  Certainly worth researching that as well if "traveling all over the 50 states" means living in other states and not working primarily from Texas.  I took the question to mean remaining a Texas resident, but traveling while working remotely for a company in another state.